# Sass Variable in CSS calc() function not working in IE

Tags: css, sass

I have a calc function as follows but it does not seem to work in IE.

in My _spacing.scss stylesheet:

```
$spacing-unit: 1em
$component-padding: calc(2* #{$spacing-unit});
```

in my8 layout scss style sheet:

```
.conainer {
   width: calc(100% - (2 * #{$component-padding}));
   max-width: 75rem;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

when this is compiled it compiles to :

```
.container {
  calc(100% - 2*calc(2*1em)));
  ...
 }
```

which seems a bit weird

Comment: Doesn't appear to be support/correctly supported [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).  You should check if it's compatible before asking on SO if there is a problem.

Comment: What's in the `$component-padding` var?  And what version of IE?

Comment: And what does "not working" mean?

Comment: And What does the compiled CSS look like?

Comment: FWIW, _can i use_ doesn't show that calc is completely unsupported, but _partially_ supported.  I verified that it can work in IE11, and [this codepen post](https://codepen.io/zachhanding/post/nested-calc-functions-and-ie11) shows someone doing the same.  However, without more information there's not much guidance the community can provide you with.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that [IE doesn't like to parse nested `calc` functions](https://codepen.io/zachhanding/post/nested-calc-functions-and-ie11).  That's not to say that it doesn't support it whatsoever, but you must omit the `calc` from the expression.  So IE11 won't respect `calc(100% - 2 * calc(2 * 1em)))` but it *should* respect `calc(100% - 2 * (2 * 1em)))`.

As a secondary note, while it *shouldn't* be a breaking concern, there are some operators in which surrounding whitespace matters in the `calc` expression.  For that reason, [MDN recommends whitespace always be included around operator for consistency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).